# Calculator in JavaScript problem with reset button

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I had a task to do a calculator which calculates 2 numbers,and for extra points a reset button but i am confused because i can't make it to work properly

```js
let n1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerText = Number(prompt("N1"))
let n2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerText = Number(prompt("N2"))
let changeR = document.getElementById("result")

function add(){
  let sum = n1 + n2
  changeR.innerText = sum
}

function sub(){
  let sum = n1 - n2
  changeR.innerText = sum
}

function mult(){
  let sum = n1 * n2
  changeR.innerText = sum
}

function divi(){
  let sum = n1 / n2
  changeR.innerText = sum
}

function rest() {
  let sum = 0
  console.log(sum)
  changeR.innerText = sum
  let n1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerText = Number(prompt("N1"))
  let n2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerText = Number(prompt("N2"))
}
```

```html
<h1>Numbers</h1>
<p id="num1"></p>
<p id="num2"></p>
<hr>
<h1>Result:<span id="result"></h1>
<hr>
<button onclick="add()">+</button>
<button onclick="sub()">-</button>
<button onclick="mult()">*</button>
<button onclick="divi()">/</button>
<button onclick="rest()">reset</button>
```

So i tried to solve my problem but i can't,when i press reset to reset the result somehow the values are still there and can't calculate the new numbers

Comment: Small programming note: make a `function setResult(value) { result.textContent = value; }` and then call that everywhere instead of having five different places where page updates might go wrong. And taking advantage of the fact that any element with an `id` attribute can be directly referenced on the JS side by that id. So you don't need `document.getElementById("num1")` for example: `num1`, `num2,` and `result` are _already_ defined on the JS side.

Comment: As for your question: remember [how variable scoping works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). If you use `let something = somethingelse`, you define a _new_ variable with a  value that does _not_ exist outside the block scope it's in. So look at the end of your reset function, and then ask yourself what those last two lines actually do.

Comment: Try making the use currying in javascript, here's snippet if you want ref: https://replit.com/@Vishwajeet4004/CalculatorCurrying#index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, all you need to do is let the variables be global.

The issue you were facing was that each function had its own variable for sum (*they were defined again with **let** and thus existed in the scope of the function sperate from their global counterpart*) and hence each function was only accessing its own variable and in the case of reset the function also had its own n1 and n2 which were populated with the latest value from the prompt but the global n1 and n2 values were not changed and as the other functions were using the global n1 and n2 to calculate the result the old result was showing for them while the reset was putting value in its own n1 and n2 every time without effecting the global n1 and n2.

Hope it helps,

```
let n1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerText = Number(prompt("N1"))
let n2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerText = Number(prompt("N2"))
let changeR = document.getElementById("result")
let sum = 0;

function add(){
sum = n1 + n2
changeR.innerText = sum
}


function sub(){
sum = n1 - n2
changeR.innerText = sum
}

function mult(){
sum = n1 * n2
changeR.innerText = sum
}

function divi(){
sum = n1 / n2
changeR.innerText = sum
}

function rest(){

sum = 0;
console.log(sum)
changeR.innerText = sum
n1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerText = Number(prompt("N1"))
n2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerText = Number(prompt("N2"))
}
```